# Display open or closed items for specific projects from VersionOne rest-1.v1/Data

Tags: versionone

When viewing specific sub projects in a single URL, is it possible to structure the URL display closed items only for one project and open + closed items for the other project. Currently the below URL will display open projects only.

http://versionone/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/PrimaryWorkitem?sel=ID.Name,ID.Number,Scope.Parent.Name&where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='Project One', 'Project Two';Scope.IsClosed='false'

Best regards,
AmiK

Comment: Just so I understand your question better -- you want open items in, say, project one and both open/closed items in project two?

Comment: Hello -  yes that is correct

Comment: try an or statement in the where clause -- like this : where=(AssetState!='Closed';Scope.Name='Project A')|(AssetState='Active','Closed';Scope.Name='Project B')